# Perl run PSGI on linux centos and apache shared hosting

Tags: perl, psgi

I have a psgi test application on a linux centos with cpanel shared hosting. How can I call it under PSGI protocol 
like:

```
http://domain.com/app.psgi
```

I mean how to enable .psgi to run under PSGI protocol. I want to be able to run any .psgi automatically under the PSGI protocol.

I know I can run it using the plackup command.

Comment: Which shared host, or a description of its platform might be the relevant information needed to get a useful answer.

Comment: It is a Linux Centos With Cpanel

Comment: Please describe what you mean by 'automatically'. Thanks.

Comment: You do not run a PSGI program the same way you run a CGI program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the share hosting used Apache, in other words mod_perl, you need avaliable mod_perl, but this is not psgi.